# How do I get the Package Parameters in Chocolatey working?

Tags: chocolatey

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to get a PackageParameter in a Chocolatey Package? According to the documentation the following should work but it doesn't for me.

Here is what I do

Install with params

```
choco install .\test-params.0.0.1.2.nupkg --params="'/SERVER:test'" -y -d
```

So far so good, in the debug output I get a line saying

```
PackageParameters='/SERVER:test'|
```

To get the Parameter in `chocolateyInstall.ps1` I use `$par = Get-PackageParameters` according the documentation.

But for some reason `$par` remains empty.

With

```
Write-Host "PackageParameters are: $par"
```

I get `PackageParameters are: System.Collections.Hashtable`

and with

```
Write-Host $par['SERVER']
```

just an empty line

Can someone enlighten me what I'm missing?

The complete debug output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/pNkzShua)

Comment: What documentation are you referring to?  Have you followed this: https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument

Comment: Also, what version of Chocolatey are you using?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark it's Chocolatey v0.10.11 (current)
Docu: https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-get-package-parameters and the one you linked.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved! The issue actually is the way the package was installed

When invoking the installation with this, PackageParameters do not work.

```
choco install .\test-params.0.0.1.2.nupkg --params="'/SERVER:test'" -y -d
```

By indicating the package source with -s (which is actually the recommended way as I found now), the PackageParameters work as expected.

```
choco install test-params -s="path/to/local/packages" --params="'/SERVER:test'" -y -d
```

Comment: thank you, your solution work for me, only using nupkg file not nuspec file